# Error in fetching files Kubuntu 13.10

Tags: konsole

> W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/dists/saucy/Release 
>   Unable to find expected entry 'partner]/binary-amd64/Packages' in
>   Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
>
> W: Failed to fetch http:
>   //archive.canonical.com/dists/$(lsb_release/-sc)/binary-amd64/Packages
>   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.150 80]
>
> W: Failed to fetch http:
>   //archive.canonical.com/dists/$(lsb_release/partner/binary-amd64/Packages
>   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.150 80]
>
> W: Failed to fetch http:
>   //archive.canonical.com/dists/$(lsb_release/-sc)/binary-i386/Packages 
>   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.150 80]
>
> W: Failed to fetch http:
>   //archive.canonical.com/dists/$(lsb_release/partner/binary-i386/Packages
>   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.150 80]
>
> E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old
>   ones used instead.

I keep getting this when I do `sudo apt-get update`. What could be causing it?

i also have trouble finding skype for kubuntu 13.10 as i cant find it anywhere. or is it not avilable?

Answer (score 0):

I have the following entries, in my /etc/apt/sources.list file:

```
  deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy main restricted 
  deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy main restricted 

  ## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
  ## distribution.
  deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates main restricted 
  deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates main restricted 

  ## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
  ## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
  ## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
  deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy universe 
  deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy universe 
  deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates universe 
  deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates universe 

  ## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
  ## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
  ## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
  ## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
  ## security team.
  deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy multiverse 
  deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy multiverse 
  deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates multiverse 
  deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates multiverse 

  ## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
  ## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
  ## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
  ## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
  ## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
  deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-backports main restricted universe multiverse 
  deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-backports main restricted universe     multiverse 

  deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-security main restricted 
  deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-security main restricted 
  deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-security universe 
  deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-security universe 
  deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-security multiverse 
  deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-security multiverse 

  ## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
  ## 'partner' repository.
  ## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
  ## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
  deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ saucy partner  
  deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ saucy partner 

  ## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
  ## developers who want to ship their latest software.
  deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy main 
  deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy main
```

You should copy this into your /etc/apt/sources.lust file, and toss whatever you had before. You may, perhaps adapt the regional repos (us....) to your country, but it will still work even in the current form. Also, here you will find skype.